# Запрос на php или js в Grafana для получения графика

Tags: javascript, php, post, grafana

Подключив Grafana к InfluxDB, хочу теперь со своего сервера посылать flux-query в grafana и получать ссылку на график по этому запросу. Есть ли у Grafana такой API.

Comment: У Grafana есть [explore](https://play.grafana.org/explore) страница, которая позволяет выполнять произвольные запросы, и видеть (упрощённые) графики. То ли это, что нужно?